# Decorator case or not?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have a contract "ArticleStorage" that every storage must be subscribe to be valid for model.
True, this is not the problem, my problem is: pagination ... or "results modification", in this case at **fetchAll**, i want modify its behavior but without adding parameters, etc

```
<?php

interface ArticleStorage
{
    // public function insert();
    // public function update();
    // public function delete();
    public function fetchAll();
}

class MySQLArticleStorage implements ArticleStorage
{
    public function fetchAll()
    {
        // SELECT * FROM `articles`;
    }
}
```

?>

How my model works.

```
class ArticlesModel
{
    public function __construct(ArticleStorage $storage)
    {

    }
}
```

in this case, I expect a "ArticleStorage" but do not know which "Storage" was given, true ... and i want to paginate or apply a results modification, using the Storage.

```
class MySQLArticleResultsModifier
{
    public function __construct(MySQLArticleStorage $storage)
    {

    }
    public function fetchAll() 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In case of a pagination, how i can modify ArticleStorage fetchAll and apply my modified query ?

Comment: In your design I was expecting an interface to fetch a page. Do you expect `fetchAll` of the `Modifier` class to return a page instead of all results?

Comment: I think class MySQLArticleResultsModifier should also extend MySQLArticleStorage and pass the instance to the constructor

Comment: Seems to me that fetchAll and pagination are incompatible concepts. Why not have add a method fetchRange(start, end)?

Comment: Decorating would change the meaning of fetchAll() which is not you would want as there might be other people who would use these objects someday. I guess better would be to add a new method to your interface like fetchSome(start, noOfItems). Your previous interface functions remain untouched. Also, you have to watch out for repetitive code in fetchSome() and fetchAll(). fetchAll() could be implemented using fetchSome().

Answer (score 0):

Is there a case where your model demands that a fetchall on top of another fetchall is possible; I don't think so, infact this is how you decide if you need a decorator or not, by answering this question to yourself

- Is the decorator function you are thinking of making works like a decoration{like a real decoration where you can put stars on your  christmas tree {decoration1}, and some toys on your tree {decoration2} at the same instance?   Otherwise there is no point in making a decorator pattern, The nature of decorator is to decorate the concrete implementations from outside world, and change the output, without being affected by the other decoration being applied to a concrete instance.

Now as to the current implementation, I think @mrhobo is quite right, your fetch function might look like

```
public function fetch($limit, $order,$sort)
```

A very smart fetch could also expect the user to send a hashtable of key-value , of the columnname = value of column by using which you can make your own select query on the fly.